# How to show message if dropdown list gets null in mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a drop down list that i fill dynamically from database. I want to show message to user if list get null(Database has no value). If database has value list should show "Select" that i have done. How can i show message "No value to select" if list gets null?
This is my drop down

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProductId, new SelectList(Model.ProductTypes, "ProductId", "ProductType"), string.Concat("-- ", "Select", " --"), new { Class = "form-control" })
```

I try this in case of null but does not work fine.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProductId, new SelectList(Model.ProductTypes, "ProductId", "ProductType"), @Model.ProductTypes==null?string.Concat("-- ", "No value to select", " --"): string.Concat("-- ", "Select", " --"), new { Class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: Is the : (colon) in your second code block a typo? (Right before the string.concat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you can set viewbag from controller and then you can check viewbag in view page.

   ```
   if (viewbag.variablename != null)
   {
       // show your message
   }
   ```
2. You have to use jquery for this. you can show your message in document.ready()` function:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
       // check for items in dropdown list
   });
   ```